# Grails Project - Common Java Project Dependency in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, grails, dependencies

All,

We have standard java projects that contain our common data model, common util classes, etc...

What I can’t seem to figure out is how, to make my Grails project (in Eclipse) have a dependency on the other standard (non Grails) java project in the workspace. When I add the project in the “Java Build Path” the project doesn’t show any compiler errors, but it when I run “Grails Tools -> Refresh Dependencies” or attempt to run the project (run-app) it fails.

This seems like it would be a pretty common thing, but I have searched all over the web and have been unable to find a solution. We are not using maven in our environment. Since we build Eclipse RCP applications on the client side, we use OSGI manifests to manage our project / bundle dependencies.

Answer (score 2):

You can use linked source directories to include the Java or Groovy dependencies in the grails project and you need to set the output directory to Project/target/classes (these configurations go into the grails project preferences in Java Build Path options -> Source Tab).

The change in the output directory allows Eclipse to detect changes in the dependencies and auto load it when running the app using grails run-app.

You can use autocomplete and debug the sources of the dependencies with this configuration.

I prepared a step and step process that includes screenshots for Java and Groovy [here](http://nazcasistemas.com/blogs/pacozarate/2013/04/18/grails-project-common-javagroovy-project-dependency-in-eclipse/)

Answer (score 0):

The documentation includes information on [customizing the build](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/4.%20The%20Command%20Line.html#4.4%20Customising%20the%20build).

You can add this to your `BuildConfig.groovy`:

```
grails.compiler.dependencies = {
    fileset (dir:"/path/to/jars")
}
```

That should get you started.

Answer (score 0):

If the dependencies are not stored in an Ivy/Maven repository then AFAIK your only option is to copy the dependencies to the `lib` directory of the Grails project.

Comment: the dependencies are not jar files that i can add it to the lib directory. They are other projects that exist in my eclipse workspace

Comment: Have you tried adding the directory where those other projects' classes are stored to the CLASSPATH of the grails project?